# Turn application into web application

Tags: web-services, web-applications, web

Please excuse the noobiness of my question. I am mostly searching here for some directions and buzzwords to start digging from.

I spent some time developing [an application in Python](https://github.com/jlengrand/FaceMovie) 
Basically, it takes a bunch of images and creates a video out of it.

It i quite simple, and uses only a few libraries (opencv and nunmpy mostly).

I designed a small gui in gtk, but I think that it would be a good idea to offer the service over the web.
I think I could reuse some of my core and design a front end that people could access in their browser.
I only need a few data to get it running (images, an email)

The thing is my web dev skills are really close to 0, and I don't exactly know where to start from . 
I don't plan on having hundreds of people a day on the platform.

People would connect, feed me with the data (link to a dropbox folder, google drive, whatever) and I would send them a message where it's finished.

If you could provide me with some names or links so that I could touch the field, I'd be really glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGI is a fine option, but if you already have Python experience Django is definitely worth checking out (it falls in the category of rhooligan's #3 except it uses Python!). Django completely takes care of all of the database backend details for you, which is a benefit over simple CGI. It also provides easy-to-use pre-defined classes for handling file uploads, images, etc. It also has a great [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/) that will get you up and running. Just be careful about whether you're using version 1.3, 1.4, or the latest dev version, because some aspects of the framework have changed fairly quickly. Make sure that you're always looking at the right version of the docs.

Another handy service to keep in mind for doing something like image processing through a web app is a hosted cloud computing service provider like [PiCloud](http://www.picloud.com/). Unless you already have a private web server with lots of memory and processing power, these cloud services that charge by the ms are really cool. They also give you 1000s of cores which could allow you to do lot's of concurrent processing. They provide a nice Python API, and it has numpy and opencv pre-installed in both v2.6 and v2.7. (They use PyOpenCV, but you also have root access to install anything you want, so you can set up the "cv2" interface if that's what you're using--actually I just looked at your GitHub and it looks like you're using the old "cv" interface. You can also install any application you want on PiCloud--it doesn't have to be Python.)

Comment: I went for the old interface to ensure that some distros would have packaged opencv, and avoid everybody having to compile from source. Didn't know about pycloud. I'll look closer. What would be the difference with and Heroku or AWS?

Comment: I haven't actually used PiCloud yet, but I'm just about to try deploying an experimental image-processing web app with it. Compared to Heroku and AWS, it looks like Heroku has monthly minimums, and AWS on-demand pricing actually looks pretty comparable, but I like the convenience of so many common Python libraries being pre-installed on PiCloud (and it even prorates your usage time to the milisecond). Also I'm not sure about concurrency on AWS. I'll see how it goes though ;)

Comment: Thx for the additional information. PiCloud indeed seem interesting for IP based applications. I think I'll give it a shot in the coming weeks. I'd be glad to know more about your application, btw :)

Answer (score 1):

You could start by looking into the [Python CGI module](http://wiki.python.org/moin/CgiScripts) and see if it will work for you. Then you'll need to do the following steps:

1. Decide on a webserver and install it, Apache is probably a good starting point.
2. Design the UI. Wireframe things out on paper paper.  Figure out how you'd ideally want the users to go through your site and what you want on each page/view.
3. Your decision in #2 drives all the decisions from this point out.  These days, most web applications are a combination of Web 1.0 and JSON/REST "services" (there's a couple of buzzwords for ya!). JQuery is a popular and widely used JavaScript library for developing the front end of your site.  That would be another thing to look at.  JQuery is completely independent from the back end and can be used with any type of back end (PHP, Ruby, Perl, .NET, etc)

Comment: Thx for the bozzwords, JQuery seem likle one of the thing I'll indeed have to work with